# Processing a data feed format

Tags: c#

I had an interesting interview question the other day, which I really struggled with.  The (highly ambitious) spec required me to write, in C#, parsers for two different data streams.  Here is a made-up example of the first stream:

```
30=EUR/USD,35=3,50=ON,51=12.5,52=13.5,50=6M,51=15.4,52=16.2,50=1Y,51=17.2,52=18.3
```

where 30 is the currency pair, 35 is the number of tenors, and 50,51,52 are the tenor,bid and ask respectively.  The bid and ask are optional, but a correct tenor-bid-ask tuple will have at least one of the two prices.  The framework code they supplied implied that the result of parsing this line should be 3 individual objects (DataElement instances).  I ended up with a rather nasty switch-statement and loop-based implementation that I am not sure actually worked.

What techniques are there for reading this kind of stream?  I tried to figure out something with recursion, which I couldn't get right.

EDIT: 
Based on @evanmcdonnall's answer (accepted) here is the fully compiling and working code, in case it's useful for anyone else.

```
        List<DataElement> Parse(string row)
    {
        string currency=string.Empty;
        DataElement[] elements = null;
        int j = 0;
        bool start = false;
        string[] tokens = row.Split(',');
        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] kv = tokens[i].Split('=');

            switch (kv[0])
            {
                case "30":
                    currency = kv[1];
                    break;
                case "35":
                    elements = new DataElement[int.Parse(kv[1])];
                    break;
                case "50":
                    if (start)
                        j++;
                    elements[j] = new DataElement() { currency = currency, tenor = kv[1] };
                    start = true;
                    break;
                case "51":
                    elements[j].bid = double.Parse(kv[1]);
                    break;
                case "52":
                    elements[j].ask = double.Parse(kv[1]);
                    break;
            }
        }
        return elements.ToList();
    }
```

The main concepts are:

- Have a separate counter for the "inner loop" of repeating items in each line
- Have a boolean flag to indicate when that "inner loop" begins
- Allocate the array of objects to store the "inner loop" results at the point where the length is known (i.e., tag 50)
- For simplicity and clarity, have a function that reads just a single line, then call it multiple times from a separate function.

Comment: It doesn't look like this is a delimited datastream, nor fixed width. I'd think your method seems reasonable

Comment: is the order of the elements always the same? I mean first you'll have the currency pair, then the number of tenors, and after that the exact number of tuples corresponding to the number of tenors?

Comment: @AndrewWalters: It looks fairly consistently delimited with `,`...

Comment: Yes, clearly comma delimited.

Comment: @ppetrov: yes, 30= always came first and was non-optional.  The number of tuples was controlled by the 35=? element, and those tuples could be be either [50=,51=], [50=,52=] or [50=,51=,52=] so the 50=? was non-optional, but either 51= or 52= could be optional but not necessarily.

Comment: @endian - Do you mean `50` was non-optional and `51` and `52` were optional? (I don't see `53` in the example but that might just be in this case)

Comment: @keyboardP: sorry, corrected now

Comment: When you say 'stream', do you mean you have to consume data serially and gradually and possibly wait to see if there is more available?  Or do you get the entire contents in one big string, and work with it from there?

Comment: I read it that each line of data would arrive fully formed - i.e., in a string variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see what's so tricky about it. However, I don't see any solution that would be better than the very specific, iteration with many conditionals solution I have in mind.

First you split on commas, then you loop over those tokens, splitting each on the equal sign to get you key value pair. You have checks for each key and a bool to track when you start/finish an item. You read the currency and use that for each object. You read key `35` and find there are 3 objects, so you allocate an array of three objects, each with 3 properties; tenor, bid, and ask. When you encounter 50 you should set a your start true. You set 50, 51, and 52 if they're there. Below is some sample code;

```
  string currency;
  int j = 0;
  bool start = false;
  string[] tokens = line.Split(',');
  for (int i =0; i < tokens.length; i++)
  {
        string[] kv = tokens[i].Split('=')
        if (kv[0] == 30)
             currency = kv[1]
        elseif (kv[0] == 35)
        {
             DateElement[] elements = new DataElement[kv[1]];
        }
        elseif (kv[0] == 50)
        {
             if (start)
                 j++;
             start = true; // flip your flag after the condition so it works for element 0
             elements[j].currency = currency;
             elements[j].tenor = kv[1];
        }
        elseif (kv[0] == 51)
             elements[j].bid = kv[1];
        elseif (kv[0] == 52)     
            elements[j].ask = kv[1];
       // if these optional values aren't there we'll just fall back into the case for 50
      // and everything will work as expected.
  }
```

The code may not be pretty, but the logic is fairly trivial and, assuming the lines format is correct, it will always work.

Comment: I didn't say it was tricky, I said I struggled with it - there's a very obvious difference between those two statements :).  I see that your code kind of follows the line I took, except that you explicitly have a separate counting variable (j) whereas I tried to combine mine with the loop variable (i), and your approach of allocating the elements array when tag 35 arrives is a nice one.  Thanks.

Comment: @endian my apologies. This kind of string processing is somewhat difficult at first but after you get used to it, it becomes very routine.

Comment: Do you need to set your 'j' variable back to 0 when you get a new 35= ?

Comment: @endian yeah, you don't want to use the the main loop var because some of the parameters are optional so doing something like `if (tokens.length -2 % 3 == x)` won't work. And yes, if there are more lines then you need to reset j. However, if there are more lines, all of that code needs to be wrapped by another loop so j will get reset. The outer loop would just be like `while (line = reader.readline() != null)`. The rest of the code could sit inside of that and would work for reading any number of lines.

Comment: Yes, there were multiple lines, so the outer while() loop was necessary.  This was the easy data format of the two to parse.  The second one had bid/ask information for the same tenor in different messages...then there was the multithreading...and the best-bid/ask selection logic...and the GUI binding...all within 2 hours.

Comment: A few notes courtesy of the compiler: currency needs a default value (=string.Empty) as does the array elements (= null), which therefore needs to be moved to outside the scope of the loop.

Comment: and elements[j] needs to be constructed when the 50= tag is found.

Answer (score 0):

30=EUR/USD,35=3,50=ON,51=12.5,52=13.5,50=6M,51=15.4,52=16.2,50=1Y,51=17.2,52=18.3

Let me try. I am not writing C# code , just giving a overview of my approach

i would break this into 2 segments Chain1={P0 , P1} and Chain2={P2......PN}

break evenly chain 2 based on value from P1. based on position of comma.

```
substr=Chain.substring(0,Chain2.IndexOf(",", P1=3));
```

We can create a [**Tuple**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) Class Collection -

```
here either i can use regex to split the string or simple substring and indexof("=")  to extract value  

var seg= new Tuple<string, int, int, >("ON", 12.5, 13.5);
```